# Excel IF formula not working

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying the following excel formula, I need cell C4 on my sheet to return the value 0 because A4 does equal B3. Here is what I've tried:

`=IF(A4='Weekly Input Data'!B$3:B$4,0,1)` and it's returning value of 1 but since A4 does = B3, 
I need it to return value 0. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `MATCH` instead?

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A4, 'Weekly Input Data'!B$3:B$4, 0)), 0, 1)
```

`MATCH` will try to find a matching value from your range and if it finds one, it will return a number.

---

I just realised that you actually can even remove the IF:

```
=ISERROR(MATCH(A4, 'Weekly Input Data'!B$3:B$4, 0))*1
```

If `MATCH` has a match, `ISERROR` returns false, i.e. 0 and 0*1 gives 0. (You did expect 0 if A4 is in B3:B4).

If `MATCH` doesn't have any match, `ISERROR` returns true, i.e. 1 and 1*1 gives 1.

---

EDIT: As per update on blank range, you can use this:

```
=IF(COUNTBLANK('Weekly Input Data'!B$3:B$4)=ROWS('Weekly Input Data'!B$3:B$4),0,ISERROR(MATCH(A4,'Weekly Input Data'!B$3:B$4,0))*1)
```

I used `COUNTBLANK` and `ROWS` to make the formula more flexible for varying ranges without making it an array formula.

Comment: So I used  this formula but how do I add if the cell in range B3:B4 is blank to return 0? and thanks soo much for your help! I've been trying to figure out the same spreadsheet for days and I'm still struggling to make it work.                                        =IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A4, 'Weekly Input Data'!B$3:B$4, 0)), 0, 1)

Comment: @user2837038 If I understand well, those are the scenarios: If B3:B4 is blank, it should return 0; if A4 is found in B3:B4, it should return 0 and if A4 is not found in B3:B4, it should return 1, correct? Just want to make sure of this before writing out the formula :)

Comment: @user2837038 Okay, I edited my answer with the new formula. :)

Comment: Yay that worked but I'm still having issues with my spreadsheet, I can't figure something out and I don't know how to describe it without actually showing you the spreadsheet. Is that possible? I'm new to this site so I don't know what's allowed or not or even if I can upload a spreadsheet? let me know, if not that's fine and I appreciate your help

Comment: @user2837038 Yes, you can upload a spreadsheet, but the site doesn't support that feature, so you can upload from an external site, such as [this](http://ge.tt/) and put the link here. Just make sure there's no sensitive info in your spreadsheet, just in case :)

Answer (score 1):

When using the formula

```
=IF(A4='Weekly Input Data'!B$3:B$4,0,1)
```

You are comparing cell `A4` with the range `'Weekly Input Data'!B$3:B$4`, not with the cell `'Weekly Input Data'!B$3`.

You have two options:

1. Compare cell `A4` with the cell `'Weekly Input Data'!B$3`
2. Lookup if the cell `A4` matches with any cell of the range `'Weekly Input Data'!B$3:B$4`

For 1. the formula is: `=IF(A4='Weekly Input Data'!B$3, 0, 1)`

For 2. the formula is: `=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A4, 'Weekly Input Data'!B$3:B$4, 0)), 0, 1)`

Answer (score 0):

On Cell C4:

```
=IF(A4=B3,0,1)
```

If your A4 (and/or B3) is in different sheet then:

```
=IF(A4='Weekly Input Data'!B$3,0,1)
```

Edit: Since now you mentioned you need to compare RANGE of datas (1 Cell to multi-Cell data)

This is what I found from this website http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/87031-formula-compare-value-one-cell-range-5-cells.html - DRJ's answer (updated to match your query):

```
=IF(ISNA(INDEX('Weekly Input Data'!B3:B7,MATCH(A4,'Weekly Input Data'!B3:B7,0))),0,1)
```

Comment: I need the formula to look at a range of cells, it will eventually be A4 compared to b3:b20. So if A4 = any of those cells it needs to equal 0